# Enable button using jQuery ajax with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following html code where the user can signup to the system.

```
<div id="usernameMSG"></div><input type="text" id="usernameID" name="username" id="usernameID" placeholder="Username" />
    <div id="passwordMSG"></div><input id="passwordID" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" disabled/>
```

Also I have the following jQuery function where check while the user typing in the database if the typed username is available.

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('main/search_user'); ?>",$("#msform").serialize(), function(data){
                                                                                                    $("#usernameMSG").html(data);
                                                                                            //
                                                                                            if     (data == 'available') {
                                                                                            $('.action-button').removeAttr('disabled');
                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                            else if (data == 'not available') {
                                                                                            $('.action-button').attr('disabled');
                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                            //
                                                                                             });
```

The main controller is the follow:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {
function search_user(){
$this->load->model('model_users');

if($this->model_users->find_user_by_username($this->input->post('username')))
                {
                echo "not available";
                return true;
                }
else
    {
    echo "available";
    return false;
    }

}
}
?>
```

The Model function is:

```
<?php
Class Model_users extends CI_Model{
public function find_user_by_username()
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('USERNAME',$this->input->post('username'));
$this->db-> limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get('USERS');

if($query->num_rows() == 1)
            {
            return true;
            }               
else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
}//end of model
```

My question is how can I enable the button if the username is available inside the JQuery function?

Comment: Maybe some one can sugest me a better way how can i check if the username is available or not inside the JQuery Function

Comment: Did you try to add checking of returned message, and changing of button properties, inside $post callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {
function search_user(){
$this->load->model('model_users');

if($this->model_users->find_user_by_username($this->input->post('username')))
                {
                    echo "not available";
                }
else
    {
       echo "available";
    }

}
}
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#usernameID').keyup(function(){
        //check if the user name is already taken
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('main/search_user'); ?>",
                $("#msform").serialize(),       
                function(data){

                    if (data == 'available') {
                            $('.action-button').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }

    });
```

Comment: and if is not available:    'else if (data == 'not available') {
                            $('.action-button').attr('disabled');
                    }' ?

Answer (score 0):

It's nice to use JSON object in php codeigniter and get JSON in jquery suceess function:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html

Then Use removeAttr:
http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

```
$('.action-button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

PHP code(from https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html):

```
$this->output
->set_content_type('application/json')
->set_output(json_encode(array('is_available' => 'true')));
```

For checking true or false you must check the json that returned by server,

```
function(result){
    if(result.is_available == 'true'){
         $('.action-button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to check? how look like my if statment?

Comment: $('.action-button').removeAttr('disabled'); and $('.action-button').attr('disabled'); its not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify what is not working?
is the button not showing or is the check on the username not working?

Did you notice the space in:
$this->db-> limit(1);

And why are you limiting the results anyway it anyway? If the users exists it exists and if it's unique it is only one entry.

Comment: The JQuery Function. Is not working Properly. If the username is not available should disable the submit button and if available should enable the submit button.

Comment: I fix the line: $this->db->limit(1); , But If the username is not available it still do not disable the button. May you can sugest me to write in a different way the JQuery code...